# How to obtain list of common users from different groups in firebase DB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Is there any way I can find if users is present in both the groups `here: user 1` so that notification/data can be sent to only that set of common users only?

As DB grows I think it will be inefficient to check if every user in one group is present in another or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You can create a list of users from GroupA, then create another list of users from GroupsB and then just simply use this line of code using Java8:

```
!Collections.disjoint(list1, list2);
```

Comment: Note that this will read both complete lists from the Firebase Database. There is Firebase API to do the same query server-side.